# Like button for each post

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to have a like button on every post, I am using firebase for storing the likes and it stores individual likes of each post, but currently, I have only 1 variable that stores likes, so if one post is liked then the likes of all posts goes up. How can I have post specific like button, which I Can then send to firebase?

These are functions to push the like button to firebase,

```
var user_key;
var user_keyArr = [];
function like(e){
    document.getElementById('like-post-module').style.display = "block";
    // set user id to the hidden input field
    document.querySelector(".like-postid").value = e.target.getAttribute("userid");
    user_key = e.target.getAttribute("userid");
    user_keyArr.push(user_key);
    document.querySelector(`[userid="${user_key}"]`).innerHTML = `&#128153;`;
    const userRef = dbRef.child('users/' + e.target.getAttribute("userid"));
    // set data to the user field
    const likePostInputsUI = document.querySelectorAll(".like-post-input");
    userRef.on("value", snap => {
        for(var i = 0, len = likePostInputsUI.length; i < len; i++) {
            var key = likePostInputsUI[i].getAttribute("data-key");
                    likePostInputsUI[i].value = "";
        }
    });
    const saveBtn = document.querySelector("#like-post-btn");
    saveBtn.addEventListener("click", saveLikeClicked);         
}

function saveLikeClicked(e) {
    var n_likes = 0;
    usersRef.on("value", snap => {
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {
            if(childSnap.val().post_likes == undefined){
                let key = childSnap.key,
                value = childSnap.val()
                n_likes = n_likes + 1
            } else {
            let key = childSnap.key,
                value = childSnap.val()
                n_likes = value.post_likes + 1
        }
        });
    });
    const userID = document.querySelector(".like-postid").value;
    const userRef = dbRef.child('users/' + userID);
    var likeListObject = {}
    const likeListInputsUI = document.querySelectorAll(".like-post-input");
    likeListInputsUI.forEach(function(textField) {
        let key = textField.getAttribute("data-key");
        let value = likes;
        likeListObject[textField.getAttribute("data-key")] = textField.value
    });
    userRef.update({
        post_likes: n_likes
    });
    document.getElementById('like-post-module').style.display = "none";
    var user_keyArr_likes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_keyArr_loc"));
    console.log(user_keyArr_likes)
    for(i=0; i<=user_keyArr.length-1; i++){
        document.querySelector(`[userid="${user_keyArr_likes[i]}"]`).innerHTML = `&#128153;`;
    }
}
```

The way it goes into firebase right now:

[image: Firebase structure]

Please suggest what I can change or add.

Comment: Pass the post id as a parameter to the function that is called when clicking the like button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the code is adding 1 to the `value.post_likes` which is updating the values of all likes, so just putting the specific key in place of that works.